# Extjs access grid record from cell editor

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have peculiar problem.
I have a regular grid in extjs 4.2 and I want to access record data from the editor.
One of the columns is defined as editor:combobox and has focus event handler.
I want to access the entire record from that event handler, how do i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a context reference inside your editor plugin, so you can call it from your focus event like this:

```
listeners: {
    focus: function (component,events) {
        var grid = component.up('grid'),
            plugin = grid.findPlugin('cellediting');
        console.log(plugin.context.record);
    }
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks man. I have hard time with extjs didnt know i can get reference to record from within component.